Extracting `minijinja` templates from a shared mutable HashMap
I have an actix-web server that has a cache of files which are stored in a struct named WebAssets (which works great!). I would like to extend this struct so that it can also contain minijinja templates, but I am getting an ownership error that I am not sure how to resolve.
The relevant part of the struct looks like this:
use std::{collections::HashMap, path::{Path, PathBuf}, sync::{Arc, RwLock}};

use minijinja::Environment;

// Key is a path to a file and value is the contents of the file as Vec<u8>
type FileMap = HashMap<PathBuf, Vec<u8>>;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct WebAssets {
    assets: Arc<RwLock<FileMap>>,
    templates: Arc<RwLock<Environment<'static>>>
}

impl WebAssets {
    pub fn build(assets: FileMap) -> Self {
        Self {
            assets: Arc::new(RwLock::new(assets)),
            templates: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Environment::empty()))
        }
    }

    // `pub fn new() -> Self` method elided for conciseness. It reads the
    // filesystem, populates the `assets`, and automatically updates the
    // contents of the hashmap if the files change.

    pub fn get<P>(&self, path: P) -> Option<Vec<u8>>
    where
        P: AsRef<Path>,
    {
        self.assets
            .read()
            .unwrap()
            .get(path.as_ref())
            .cloned()
    }

    // other irrelevant methods elided for conciseness
}

I would like to implement a function or method similar to the following:
fn read_templates_from_assets(assets: Arc<RwLock<FileMap>>) -> Result<Environment<'static>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut env = Environment::new();
    if let Ok(assets) = assets.read() {
        for (path, data) in assets.iter() {
            if path.starts_with("templates") {
                let path = path.to_str().ok_or("Invalid UTF-8 sequence in path")?;
                let data = std::str::from_utf8(&data)?;
                env.add_template(path, data)?;
            }
        }
    };
    // does not compile
    Ok(env)
}

Returning either Ok(Environment::new()) or switching let path = "hello" and let data = "world" instead works fine, but the function above returns the following compilation error:
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `assets`
  --> src/templates.rs:52:5
   |
43 |         for (path, data) in assets.iter() {
   |                             ------ `assets` is borrowed here
...
52 |     Ok(env)
   |     ^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `assets`
  --> src/templates.rs:52:5
   |
42 |     if let Ok(assets) = assets.read() {
   |                         ------ `assets` is borrowed here
...
52 |     Ok(env)
   |     ^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.

I read the following answers relating to this error, but don't see a clear solution: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
If I understand the error correctly, assets is dropped before the end of the function body, and env is still holding a reference to data owned by the function, but it's not clear to me how that is the case.
I am open to changing the signature of the templates field or the read_templates_from_assets function (or method), but it would be challenging to change the signature of the assets field in the struct, since a lot of other Actix code relies on the file cache.
I tried multiple variations of the code above:

making the function a method
adding non-static lifetimes to Environment and the function
defining the templates using static TEMPLATES: LazyLock<Arc<RwLock<FileMap>>> = LazyLock::new(|| Arc::new(RwLock::new(HashMap::new())));
passing in templates in addition to assets
adding if let Ok(templates) = templates.write() {  before or after if let Ok(assets) = assets.read() {

Unfortunately I see similar borrow checker issues. I also previously used askama instead of minijinja, but I would like to dynamically add templates instead of compiling them in.
Rust version:
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.82.0 (f6e511eec 2024-10-15)


If I understand the error correctly, assets is dropped before the end of the function body, and env is still holding a reference to data owned by the function, but it's not clear to me how that is the case. – It's not clear what part you don't understand, assets is a local variable, (created in if let Ok(assets)), assets.iter() → path.to_str() is a chain that borrows from it, you then insert it into env: env.add_template(path, data) which must hold on to it for the remaining duration of the program ('static  in Environment<'static>) which extends past the end of the function.

You can't return an Environment<'static> borrowing from a function’s local variables, but you can certainly do stuff with the environment inside such a function. Is there a reason that won't work?

The error occurs because add_template is restrictive and holds the strings for the lifetime of the environment, which in this case is 'static. The solution is to enable the Minijinja loader feature and use the alternate method called add_template_owned which allows you to pass in strings:
fn read_templates_from_assets(assets: Arc<RwLock<FileMap>>) -> Result<Environment<'static>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut env = Environment::new();
    if let Ok(assets) = assets.read() {
        for (path, data) in assets.iter() {
            if path.starts_with("templates") {
                let path = path.to_string_lossy().to_string();
                let template = String::from_utf8(data.to_vec())?;
                env.add_template_owned(path, template)?;
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(env)
}

